# Quartus II Error (18994): configuration scheme "passive serial" is not valid for the device

Tags: quartus-ii

I'm trying to synthesize a System Verilog design into a Stratix 10 device using quartus II v.17 but keep getting the following error.

> Error (18994): configuration scheme "passive serial" is not valid for the device

All my top-level ports have been assigned VIRTUAL_PIN ON as this is just a small part of a larger design and I just want to see if it synthesizes. The error occurs for all Stratix 10 devices.

What is causing the error and how do I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Off the top of my head, try changing the Programmer to active serial in the drop down box.

Comment: I'm actually just trying to synthesize the RTL for a Stratix 10 device and not program a real device.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution was received on the Altera Forums.

go to Asigments-> Device -> Device and Pin options -> Configuration to change configuration mode. 
Also you can try to play with settings in Asigments-> Device -> Device and Pin options -> Dual-Purpose Pins section

The tcl commands are

> set_global_assignment -name STRATIXV_CONFIGURATION_SCHEME "ACTIVE SERIAL X1"

It fixed the problem.